# Submartingale characterization

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

is there a characterization of submartingales in terms of stopping times similar to the martingale case in [A martingale characterization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1440889/a-martingale-characterization).

Especially is the following true:
If $X$ is an adapted stochastic process with cadlag paths and $\mathrm{E}|X_t|<\infty \forall t\geq 0$, tfae:

1. X is a submartingale
2. For every bounded stopping time $\tau$ we have $\mathrm{E}X_{\tau} \geq \mathrm{E}X_0$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following construction satisfies 2. but not 1.

Let $W$ be standard Brownian motion.

For $0 \le  t\le 1$ set $X_t= W_t^2$.

For $1 \le t \le 2$ set $X_t=X_1(1-t)$. Note that $\mathbb{E}(W_t^2)=1$ so that $\mathbb{E}(X_{t})\ge 0 \text{ for } t\le 2$

For $2 \le t$ set $X_t=X_2+W_{t-2}^2$

The process $X$ is not a submartingale since $\mathbb{E}(X_2)<X_1$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see why 2. is satisfied, or why/if it is natural. Is there an idea behind the construction that I miss?

Comment: There was an error in my original answer. I have now edited the definition of $X_t$ for $1<t<2$. Now $X_t$ cannot be negative for any $t$, therefore $\mathbb{E}(X_{\tau})\ge \mathbb{E}(X_0)=0$

Comment: Even simpler: $X_t = t/(t^2+1)$ (non-random).